# iOS - Improving Stability of UI Test Button Tap in TableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, testing, button

I'm looking for ways to improve the stability of my current UI Test for a Button in a Table Cell in iOS Swift. The UI test seems to be stable locally (run it 100 times, repetitively) and it ran successfully but on CI, it's flacky.

So the UI test involves clicking the first Pay button (Pay Button) in a Table Cell and an alert will appear. Local test works as it should but in CI test, it seems that the tap() sometimes doesn't trigger the button and no alert appears, hence assertElementExists for Alert fails.

I believe the issue stems from this declaration line of code var payButton: XCUIElement in AccountDetailsScreen.swift file. I appreciate your help

[image]

**AccountDetailsUITests.swift**

```
import XCTest

class AccountDetailsTests: UITestBaseTestCase {
    
    func testAccountDetailsAlertForPayButton() throws {
        try setupAndPrepare()

        TransactionsFlow().showTransactions(for: Fixtures.account)

        let accountDetailsScreen = AccountDetailsScreens.TransactionsList().waitUntilReady()

        sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.3)
        accountDetailsScreen.payButton.tap()
        assertElementExists(accountDetailsScreen.payAlertView, timeout: 10)
        accountDetailsScreen.oKAlertButton.tap()
     }
}
```

**AccountDetailsScreen.swift**

```
import XCTest

class AccountDetailsScreens: BaseScreen {
   // Other Code
   class TransactionsList: BaseScreen {
     var payButton: XCUIElement {
            app.cells.containing(.button, identifier: "TilePayButton").firstMatch.buttons["TilePayButton"]
     }
     lazy var oKAlertButton = app.alerts.buttons["okayButtonCollectionAlertAccountDetails"]
     lazy var payAlertView = app.alerts["payAlertView"]
   }
}
```